# Can't get "has_sub_field()" to work in a conditional

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Everything is working fine, except the `<?php has_sub_field('vimeo_id'); ?>` line. I want it so that if the user has filled out that field, it displays. Otherwise, nothing shows. However, when the user doesn't fill out the field, it still shows. What have I done wrong?

```
<?php if( have_rows('project') ): ?>

    <ul>

        <?php while( have_rows('project') ): the_row(); ?>

            <li><a href="#<?php the_sub_field('project_name'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('project_name'); ?></a></li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php while( have_rows('project') ): the_row(); ?>

        <div id="<?php the_sub_field('project_name'); ?>">

            <?php has_sub_field('vimeo_id'); ?>

                <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/<?php the_sub_field('vimeo_id'); ?>?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="750" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This question should be asked on the ACF support forum. Support for this plugin is off topic here unfortunately. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `has_sub_field()` method inside an `if()` statement. I've only included the affected code below to highlight the specific changes required.

```
if (has_sub_field('vimeo_id')): // Added if()
    // ...
endif;
```

You also need to a use the `get_sub_field()` function here as opposed to the `has_sub_field()` function:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo get_sub_field('vimeo_id'); ?>"></iframe>
```